# Sometimes user profiles fail to load questions or answers

Tags: bug, profile-page, mobile-web

On the “Profile” tab on users’ pages on the mobile site, sometimes it just completely fails to load questions and answers if you choose to sort by votes:
[image]

Switching from votes to newest then reloading and switching back fixes it. This is a weird bug, so I’m reporting it here.

Comment: Likely something on your end, otherwise we'll be getting lots more such reports. Check the connection, maybe it's disconnecting a lot?

Comment: I’m deleting; this problem doesn’t happen anymore.